# inject ngRoute in requiredjs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angular-routing

I am tring to insert angular route in an angular project which has also a requiredjs.

app.js looks like this:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'lib',
    paths: {
        app: '../app',
        jquery: 'jquery-2.1.3.min',
        angular: 'angular',
        route: 'angular-route'
    },
    shim: {
       'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'route': {
            deps: ['angular'],
            exports: 'route'
        }
    }
});

// Start loading the main app file. Put all of
// your application logic in there.
requirejs(['app/main']);
```

main.js looks like this:

```
define(['route', "angular", 'app/navController'], function (route, angular, navController) {
    var app = angular.module('mainFrameModule', 'ngRoute');
    app.controller('navController', navController);

});
```

when I try to run the web site i get the follwing error described in:
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=mainFrameModule

And when I debug the main.js, route is undefined.

can anyone help me to solve this problem?

thanks in advance

kobi

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `exports` option for either angular or ngRoute. Try this shim config

```js
    shim: {
       'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'route': ['angular']
    }
```

and your main.js

```js
define(['angular', 'app/navController', 'route'], function (angular, navController) {
    var app = angular.module('mainFrameModule', 'ngRoute');
    app.controller('navController', navController);

});
```